# jQuery photo carousel (that looks like a real carousel)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, photo, carousel

I am on the lookout for a jQuery photo carousel that can display 3 images at a time, and circle through x amount of photos (and when reaching the last, starting with the first photo again).

I made a quick mock-up of what i am looking for:

[image]

So there is 3 photos vissible, the middle one beeing the 'main' one and a bit bigger than the previous and next (left and right). Upon clicking the next/previous arrows the next or previous photo slides into the middle and thereby becomes the main photo.

Any ideas to where i can find such a jQuery plugin/script?

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATED 3** *Improved Version* ( With Fancybox )

This is for the sake and for all people that asked me for that! ;)

**DEMO:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-photo-carousel-that-looks-like-a-real-carousel/

---

This is for **OP** only:

**UPDATED 2**  - With ( Next Prev ) Buttons - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/iduyu

```
$(function() {
$('.carousel').carousel();
});

(function($) {
$.fn.carousel = function() {
// 5 minutes lightweight carousel
// Copyright/Author (c) Luca Filosofi > aseptik@gmail.com
// License Public
    $carousel = $(this);
    $carousel.wrap('<div id="carousel_wrapper"></div>');
    $carousel.parent().append('<div class="button" id="left"></div>'+
                              '<div class="button" id="right"></div>');

    $('img',this).attr('class', 'inactive');
    $('img:eq(1)',this).attr('class', 'left');
    $('img:eq(2)',this).attr('class', 'active');
    $('img:eq(3)',this).attr('class', 'right');

    $carousel.fadeIn(500);

    $('.button').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var mode = this.id;
        var $button = $('.' + mode );

        $button.css({ 
            'z-index' : 9999 , 
            'opacity': 0.8
        }).animate({
            'left': '90px',
            'width': '320px',
            'top': '0px',
            'opacity': 1
        }, 500, function() {

          //lightbox
          $(this).attr({'class':'active'})
          .removeAttr('style');
        });

        $button.prev().css({
            'opacity': 0.5 
        }).animate({
            'left': '0px',
            'width': '240px',
            'top': '30px',
            'opacity': 1
        }, 400, function() {

            $(this).attr('class', 'left').removeAttr('style');
            $(this).prevAll().attr('class', 'inactive');
        });

        $button.next().css({
            'opacity': 0.5 
        }).animate({
            'left': '260px',
            'width': '240px',
            'top': '30px',
            'opacity': 1
        }, 400, function() {

            $(this).attr('class', 'right').removeAttr('style');
            $(this).nextAll().attr('class', 'inactive');
        });

        if (mode == 'left') 
        $('img:last' , $carousel).prependTo($carousel);
        if (mode == 'right') 
        $('img:first' , $carousel).appendTo($carousel);

    });
}
})(jQuery);​
```

---

> <del>you are looking for this:
>   http://web.enavu.com/demos/3dcarouselwip/</del>

Comment: Very close - only thing i can find is that i does not work in IE, which is a must :( it must be crossbrowser compatable (IE 6+7+8, Firefox, Chrome and Safari)

Comment: Looks very cool - thx :) I have played around with it, trying to get it to use 2 buttons for forward/next, instead of the previous and next image - but no luck. Also i tried to implement a lightbox behavior on the active image and making it so that it is a div that is rotated instead of an image (a div with the image inside) - this gives greater flexibility towards styling etc. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you, please, tell how you added the lightbox part? thank you.

Comment: @hgulyan : http://ask.altervista.org/demo/jquery-photo-carousel-that-looks-like-a-real-carousel/

Comment: great, I didn't hope to get an answer. That's almost what I've wanted. please, place your link here as an answer, so I can accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305303/how-to-add-a-jquery-box-to-carousel A big thank you. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### [Cloud Carousel - A 3d Carousel in Javascript](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm)

It seems to do exactly what you're looking for