# How to add a JQuery Box to Carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm trying to add a jquery box to this carousel

http://jsbin.com/iduyu

Here's the source

http://jsbin.com/iduyu/edit

I'm trying to add  tag to every  and after that it stops working. I'm not sure were I should make changes to add a box (**lightbox** or any other box that has next and previous buttons)

Thank you for any guide and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the demo http://ask.altervista.org/demo/jquery-photo-carousel-that-looks-like-a-real-carousel/

Comment: Hey aSeptik, I've tried to save the demo on my computer and it doesn't work. Maybe the problem is in the src attribute value?